# Creating password parameters for Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, object

Attempting to create a sing up procedure in Ruby. I have the length of seven characters met in the code but the password must also contain the following:

- Uppercase character
- Lowercase character
- Number
- Symbol

Having trouble inputing these requirements into the code. Any help is appreciated.

```
puts "Please enter your password"
my_password = gets
if my_password.length < 7
    puts "Your password is not long enough"
elsif my_password.length >= 7
    print my_password
end
```

Comment: What have you tried? regular expressions can check for requirements like that.

Answer (score 4):

1. you should `chomp` the input from `gets`, otherwise it’ll contain a trailing carriage return.
2. to meet all the criteria, you should explicitly check for all of them.

Like this:

```
puts "Please enter your password"
my_password = gets.chomp
case
when my_password.length < 7
  puts "Your password is not long enough"
when my_password !~ /[A-Z]/
  puts "Your password must contain an uppercase letter"
when my_password !~ /[a-z]/
  puts "Your password must contain a lowercase letter"
when my_password !~ /\d/
  puts "Your password must contain a digit"
when my_password !~ /[!?=_-]/
  puts "Your password must contain one of those: [!?=_-]"
else
  print my_password
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
def get_password
  loop do
    puts "Please enter your password"
    my_password = gets.chomp
    str =
    case my_password
    when /\A.{,6}\z/     then "seven characters"
    when /\A[^A-Z]+\z/   then "one uppercase letter"
    when /\A[^a-z]+\z/   then "one lowercase letter"
    when /\A\D+\z/       then "one digit"
    when /\A[^$%&!]+\z/  then "one symbol"
    else break my_password
    end
    puts "Passwords must contain at least #{str}" 
  end
end
```

```
pw = get_password
  #=> "abcDEF123$$$"
puts pw
"abcDEF123$$$"
```

Note that the method will not return until a valid password has been obtained. What constitutes a permissible symbol must of course be defined.

If a value is to be display it generally is best to return the value from a method, then display it. That way the same method can be used to obtain a password that is to be used in ways other than merely displaying it.
[image]
One could alternatively write the following.

```
R = /
    \A
    (?=.{7})      # match seven chars in a positive lookahead
    (?=.*\p{Ll})  # match a lowercase letter in a positive lookahead
    (?=.*\p{Lu})  # match an uppercase letter in a positive lookahead
    (?=.*\d)      # match a digit in a positive lookahead
    (?=.*[$%&!])  # match a symbol in a positive lookahead
    /x            # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

```
def get_password
  loop do
    puts "Please enter your password"
    my_password = gets.chomp
    break my_password if my_password.match?(R)
    puts "Passwords must contain at least seven characters, one uppercase"
    puts "letter, one lowercase letter and one symbol"
  end
end
```

```
pw = get_password
  #=> "aA1$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"
```

The regular expression is conventionally written as follows.

```
R = /\A\(?=.{7})(?=.*\p{Ll})(?=.*\p{Lu})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$%&!])/
```

Comment: I had nothing to do with those multicoloured stars. They fell onto my screen while I was writing my answer. You can thank stackoverflow for that.